# JSON like array of dynamic objects

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I want to create an array of dynamic objects, similar to the JSON pattern.  I am using this to allow my `Breadcrumb` class take in argumens that define the output characteristics.  I am thinking it would look something like this

```
breadcrumbs.Add(new Breadcrumb() { 
    Title = "Page name", 
    Attributes = { class = "myclass", data-info="info stuff" } 
});
```

I would then iterate through this array when I display the breadcrum to output something like this

```
<a href="" title="Page name" class="myclass" data=info="into stuff">...</a>
```

The question is can I do this dynamically without creating boiler plate code to sit inbetween i.e. `BreadcrumAttribute` that may specify the attribute name and then data.

I have seen a similar pattern elsewhere within MVC.NET but cannot remember where it was...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can use anonymous type like this:

```
breadcrumbs.Add(new Breadcrumb() { 
    Title = "Page name", 
    Attributes = new { @class = "myclass", datainfo="info stuff" } 
});
```

`data-info` is not allowed as property name so I changed it to `datainfo`, you can name it also `data_info`

or define it as `Dictionary<string,string>` and use it like:

```
breadcrumbs.Add(new Breadcrumb() { 
    Title = "Page name", 
    Attributes = new Dictionary<string, string>() { { "class", "myclass" }, { "data-info", "info" } }
});
```

Comment: This looks like what I'm after - What type would Attributes be?

Comment: @Chris they will be AnonymousType http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397696.aspx

Comment: How do I define that as part of a class though? I cannot use `var` within a class definition...

Comment: @Chris define it as `Object`, or use second solution with dictionaries. You can also use `dynamic` instead of `Object`

Answer (score 1):

Make Breadcrumb.Attributes a Dictionary

```
class Breadcrumb {
    public string Title;
    public Dictionary<string,string> Attributes;
}
```

and then..

```
        var breadcrumbs = new List<Breadcrumb>
            {
                new Breadcrumb()
                    {
                        Title = "Page name",
                        Attributes =
                            new Dictionary<string, string>
                                {
                                    {"class", "myclass"}, 
                                    {"data-info", "info stuff"}
                                }
                    }
            };
```

Comment: You know, I was so busy thinking about clever things I never even thought to think simple. Thanks!

Comment: The other answer is probably more elegant though !